# Support Vector Machine (SVM) and S3VM

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, svm

I am working Support Vector Machine (SVM) and S3VM
I want to ask few things for understanding about SVM and S3VM.
1) In SVM we are trying to maximize the width of support vectors. In S3VM, do we also try to maximize the width of support vectors? what is the basic concepts.
2) What is hat loss in S3VM and Why we used in S3VM learning?

Comment: `In SVM we are trying to maximize the width of support vectors` An SVM maximizes the width of the margin (between the support vectors and the separating hyperplane).

Comment: yes, I understand this.But what will be in case S3VM?

Answer (score 2):

S3VM stands for semi-supervised support vector machines. Semi-supervised machine learning is a class of machine learning that you have some labeled data sets and also an amount of unlabeled data.
The semi-supervised learning approach is motivated from the fact that it is easier (and cheaper) to collect unlabeled training examples. For example, it is easy to crawl the web and collect images but it is much more difficult to do with their associated labels.
As far as S3VM go, you start with the SVM formulation and then modify the constraints of the optimization problem to formulate a S3VM.
For more details in the formulation check out this paper:
http://papers.nips.cc/paper/1582-semi-supervised-support-vector-machines.pdf